# How to make gradient not change colours when scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am using map to create several divs that should have a consistent gradient background that changes over each div. I currently have the gradient consistent across the different divs, but when I scroll, the background colours change. I want the background colours to stay the same no matter how I scroll.

See the two images below of the same divs.

If I scroll down (it's more purple): [Scrolling to bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeYYp.png)

If I scroll up (it's more blue): [Scrolling to top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSf4c.png)

```
const ColourfulBackground = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  width: 1111px;
  height: 194px;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #896bff 0%, #19fbff 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
`;

const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  row-gap: 48px;
  align-items: center;
`;

const Component = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
       {arrayOfItems.map((value) => (
           <>
             <ColourfulBackground />
           </>
       ))}
    </Container>
   )
}

export default Component
```

I tried to make the background gradient consistent with `background-attachment: fixed`.
I also tried to make the child element's position relative.

Comment: do you want to have one color like purple color only??

Comment: @Developer I want the gradient to not change when scrolling. So it would alway be purple at the top divs and blue at the bottom divs. Currently, the top divs can be purple or blue depending on scroll.

Comment: are you styling each div with gradient?? Like each div has gradient color?? Right?

Comment: @Developer Each div should have a gradient

Comment: as you have gradient on each div. Definetly ,when you scroll, the gradient has two colors stops, the other color will be shown. If you want to contain same color, then give same color stops.